# Docker Error in VMWare

Tags: windows, docker, vmware

I am running Windows 10 EDU in a VMWare virtual machine and have Docker installed. When I load the VM, Docker loads for a couple minutes, then errors out with the below message:

Docker hv-sock proxy (vsudd) is not reachable
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.ConnectToVsud(TaskCompletionSource`1 vmId) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line 266
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStart(Settings settings, String daemonOptions) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line 250
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings, String daemonOptions) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line 123
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line 47
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line 145

Can anyone tell me what this means?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to be a known issue when running Docker on top of Windows 10: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/606

There are a couple workarounds provided in that chain that you might have some luck with.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check this out.